# Is it possible to calculate date range in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, range

I think the answer is yes, however my question may not be quite accurate, can't quite use words to describe what I really mean and so I have come up with a rather silly example to illustrate what I am trying to ask.

Suppose that a wearer must continuously wear a hat and whenever it changes the hat it must record the date and the name of the new that.

Using the three tables below, Is it possible to tell `(SELECT)` the hat that the receiver was wearing when sender made the compliment ? I am trying to avoid placing a sixth column in the *Compliment* table with the PK of *Hat*.

I would like to get one row as return rather than all the hats with a date greater then the date of the compliment.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are looking for this:

```
SELECT
  c.id,
  c.sender,
  c.receiver,
  c.compliment,
  c.date,
  h.hat
FROM (
  SELECT
    compliment.id,
    compliment.sender,
    compliment.receiver,
    compliment.compliment,
    compliment.date,
    max(hat.date) mx
  FROM
    compliment INNER JOIN hat
    ON compliment.receiver = hat.wearer AND compliment.date>=hat.date
  GROUP BY
    compliment.id,
    compliment.sender,
    compliment.receiver,
    compliment.compliment,
    compliment.date) c
  LEFT JOIN hat h
  ON c.receiver = h.wearer AND h.date=c.mx
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bdb8/4).

**Edit**

A cleaner version can be written as this:

```
SELECT
  compliment.*,
  hat.hat
FROM (
  SELECT
    compliment.id,
    receiver,
    max(hat.date) mx
  FROM
    compliment LEFT JOIN hat
    ON compliment.receiver = hat.wearer
       AND compliment.date >= hat.date
  GROUP BY
    compliment.id,
    compliment.receiver
  ) max_date
  INNER JOIN compliment ON max_date.id=compliment.ID
  LEFT JOIN hat ON max_date.mx = hat.date AND max_date.receiver=hat.wearer
```

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying to achieve and your SELECT looks the answer but I'm not sure if it will return more than one hat as a result using ">=" ? I haven't implemented the DB yet and can't test it. I may add that I am looking for one row as return. Many thanks.

Comment: @twimB i forgot the GROUP BY part, now it should be fixed, and I added a sql fiddle. My query will calculate the maximum date of when the receiver changed hat, and then it returns the name of that hat, it will return only a hat for every receiver.

Answer (score 2):

I think the simplest formulation is a nested `select` statement:

```
select c.*,
       (select h.hat
        from hat h
        where h.wearer = c.receiver and
              h.date <= c.date
        order by date desc
        limit 1
       ) as hat
from compliment c;
```

Nested selects are not my favorite SQL construct.  But this happens to be a case where they capture the logic quite efficiently.

For performance reasons, I would suggest having an index on `hat(wearer, date)`.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I am fiddle-ling with all the SELECT statements.